# include symfony base assets that aren't in a bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use Assetic to include my base css and js assets that aren't in a bundle. They're located in `MySymfonyApp/app/Resources/public/css/` and `MySymfonyApp/app/Resources/public/js/`.

I have the following in my `base.html.twig` template but i'm getting 404s

```
{% stylesheets '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/css/*' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}

   {% javascripts
        '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/jQuery.js'
        '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/*' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

I've also tried the following with the same result.

```
{% stylesheets '../app/Resources/public/css/*' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

How do i reference assets that aren't in bundles?

Answer (score 1):

**solution:**

assets in `app/Resources/public/*` are a special case. They can easily be managed.

These will *all* be copied (or symlinked) to `web/public/*` if you invoke the console command:

```
app/console assets:install web
```

... or ...

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

Now the assets can be included from the `web`-folder directly.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

---

**tip:**

If you need to fetch assets from other directories relative to the kernel-rootdir.

You can do something like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    assets:
        css_boostrap: 
            inputs:
                -  %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
                -  %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/myself/bootstrap-theme/*.css
        js_jquery:
             inputs:
                 - %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js
```

Now execute the console command ...

```
app/console assetic:dump
```

... and include them in one of your templates:

```
{% stylesheets '@css_boostrap' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```